# VS2022 17.9.3 C# interactive window, cannot use System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json-serialization, c#-interactive

I get the following errors if I run Json import code in C# Interactive

From VS2022, View->Other Windows->C# interactive

Anyone knows how to import the libraries in C# interactive to get this to work, current version:

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 4.9.0-3.24121.1 ()

```
> using System;
. using System.Text.Json;
(2,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> var x = 500m;
> JsonSerializer.Serialize(x)
(1,1): error CS0103: The name 'JsonSerializer' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 2):

- Add the Nuget package `System.Text.Json` to your project.
- Find the path to the .dll (can be seen in the properties window of the package, I.e.

> C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\8.0.3\lib\net8.0\System.Text.Json.dll

- Reference the assembly in the C# Interactive window: `#r <path_to_dll>`

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to add it with relative name instead of full absolute path?

Comment: @BigChief Either it works with a relative path or it doesn't. Try it out. (I.e. relative to what?)

Comment: good question, I was thinking current opened vs2022 solution, but I guess the intermediate window has a very different current path